# Php Variable is null when i pass it to the array

Tags: php, onesignal

I am trying to send user-specific web notifications with onesignal and i solved everything except this variable null problem. 
I use that variable multiple times and there is no problem except these lines:

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_POST["sub"]))
     {
         $my_variable= $_POST["t1"];

         $SQL = "some sql here";

         if (mysqli_query($db, $SQL)) {
             echo $my_variable;
             echo "<br>";



             function sendMessage(){
                 $content = array(
                     "en" => 'test message'
                 );

                 $fields = array(
                     'app_id' => "5b0eacfc-3ac8-4dc6-891b-xxxxx",
                     'filters' => array(array("field" => "tag", "key" => "key", "relation" => "=", "value" => "$my_variable")),
                     'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
                     'contents' => $content
                 );

                 $fields = json_encode($fields);
                 print("\nJSON sent:\n");
                 print($fields);

                 $ch = curl_init();
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx'));
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

                 $response = curl_exec($ch);
                 curl_close($ch);

                 return $response;
             }

             $response = sendMessage();
             $return["allresponses"] = $response;
             $return = json_encode( $return);
```

The result is :

```
     1 JSON sent: {"app_id":"5b0eacfc-3ac8-4dc6-891b-xxxxx","filters":[{"field":"tag","key":"key","relation":"=","value":"null"}],"data":{"foo":"bar"},"contents":{"en":"test message"}}
```

I tried so many variations with/without quotas , json_encode() function but couldn't pass that variable to that array.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($my_variable)` and see the result. Where are you declaring the variable? include that part of the code in your question

Comment: `"null"` doesn't look right to me, this is a literal text of the word null and not the null type.

Comment: Likewise, in your code you have `" $my_variable"`, so there should always be a space character in the value too. Post your **actual** code, with the value of `$my_variable` as others have asked.

Comment: It should just be `"value" => $my_variable`.

Comment: added the actual code. @fubar

Comment: @PBSDR - you still haven't posted the actual value of `$my_variable`, and your code formatting needs fixing (again).

Comment: var_dump($my_variable) returns null. It is showing the exact value with the echo function inside of the second if statement but it is null in function. @MehdiBounya

Comment: As @Scuzzy said, the NULL in your JSON is "sketchy"... what is the value you are submitting to `$_POST["t1"]`?

Comment: It's a value of the select with values of 0-1-2 . You can see the echo $my_variable is showing as "1" in the result.Sorry it returns as null when i pass the variable without quotas. I edited it. @MehdiBounya

Comment: Well for starters, `$my_variable` is out of scope. You'd need to pass it as a parameter to your `sendMessage()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is out of scope.

You define `$my_variable` outside of the function `sendMessage()`, but proceed to try and use it within the function, without passing it as a parameter.

This can be fixed with the following:

```
function sendMessage($filterValue) 
{
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'test message'
    );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "5b0eacfc-3ac8-4dc6-891b-xxxxx",
        'filters' => array(array("field" => "tag", "key" => "key", "relation" => "=", "value" => $filterValue)),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage($my_variable);
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);
```